# Ext.data.store POST data in JSON format issue

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs4, http-post

I'm trying to make EXT JSON store to send data using JSON, however it does not seem to be working.
Here is simple code:

```
       var myStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    //model: 'User',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/users.svc',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        },
        actionMethods: {
            create: 'POST', read: 'POST', update: 'POST', destroy: 'POST'
        },
        extraParams: { test: 'test' }
    },
        listeners: {
            beforeload: function (store, operation, options) {
                //alert(operation.params);
            }
        },
    autoLoad: true
});
```

Since I defined JSON "writer", my expectation that parameterswould be send to server using JSON.
However it's still doing regular POST with following body:
`test=test&page=1&start=0&limit=25`

While my expectation is that POST should have the following body: `{test:'test',page:1,start:0}`

I would appreciate any help

P.S. I'm using EXTJS 4.0.7

Answer (score 2):

proxy.read always use params, NOT jsonData, so store.load can't post json

http://ahlearns.wordpress.com/2012/08/16/ext-js-4-load-a-data-store-using-json-params/

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.data.proxy.JsonAjaxProxy', {
extend:'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
alias:'proxy.jsonajax',

actionMethods : {
    create: "POST",
    read: "POST",
    update: "POST",
    destroy: "POST"
},

buildRequest:function (operation) {
    var request = this.callParent(arguments);

        // For documentation on jsonData see Ext.Ajax.request
        request.jsonData = request.params;
        request.params = {};

        return request;
},

/*
 * @override
 * Inherit docs. We don't apply any encoding here because
 * all of the direct requests go out as jsonData
 */
applyEncoding: function(value){
    return value;
}

});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: how to send in the request body though? I saw the link but not able to figure this out?

Comment: This question is about "Ext.data.store POST data in JSON format",
so use 
  store.load({params:{a:1,b:2}})
to post params as json

Comment: Looks like this should work, wasn't it ? But how would you distinguish the actions, without defining the `api`config like
`api: { create: 'server/jsonProxy.php?action=create', read: undefined, update: 'server/jsonProxy.php?action=update', destroy: 'server/jsonProxy.php?action=destroy' },`

Answer (score 0):

Shift the `proxy` definition to the `model`.

E.g.

```
Ext.define('User', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: ['id', 'name', 'email'],
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: '/users.svc',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'users'
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data'
    },
    actionMethods: {
        create: 'POST', read: 'POST', update: 'POST', destroy: 'POST'
    },
    extraParams: { test: 'test' }
}
});
```

Then configure the store like so:

```
 var myStore = new Ext.data.Store({
   model: 'User'
   });
```

The store will use the proxy specified in the model.
Hope this helps!